# Understanding single/multi class patterns

Tags: html, css, class, architecture, semantic-markup

I'm currently trying to digest this article by Nicolas Gallagher: [About HTML semantics and front-end architecture](http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-html-semantics-front-end-architecture/)

I'm struggling to understand this paragraph under the heading 'The "multi-class" pattern'…

> I’ve found it to be a more scalable pattern. For example, take the base btn component and add a further 5 types of button and 3 additional sizes. Using a “multi-class” pattern you end up with 9 classes that can be mixed-and-matched. Using a “single-class” pattern you end up with 24 classes.

When he says take the *btn* component and add a further 5 types of button, does he mean as independent classes, such as *btn-danger*, *btn-primary* etc. If so in what context are the 3 additional sizes?

Would be extremely helpful is someone could explain how he arrives at 9 classes using a "multi-class" pattern and 24 classes using a "single-class" pattern.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here or have failed to grasp a simple concept.

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what he is getting at is that under a "single-class" scheme, you would need a "combined" class for every possible combination. So, following his example of "base btn component and add a further 5 types of button and 3 additional sizes":

**Multi-class** (9)

- .btn
- .btn-primary
- .btn-danger
- .btn-success
- .btn-link
- .btn-warning
- .btn-extra-small
- .btn-small
- .btn-large

  ```
  <a href="http://google.com/" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
      Example multi-class link
  </a>
  ```

**Single-class** (24)

- .btn
- .btn-extral-small
- .btn-small
- .btn-large
- .btn-primary
- .btn-primary-extra-small
- .btn-primary-small
- .btn-primary-large
- .btn-danger
- .btn-danger-extra-small
- .btn-danger-small
- .btn-danger-large
- .btn-success
- .btn-success-extra-small
- .btn-success-small
- .btn-success-large
- .btn-link
- .btn-link-extra-small
- .btn-link-small
- .btn-link-large
- .btn-warning
- .btn-warning-extra-small
- .btn-warning-small
- .btn-warning-large

  ```
  <a href="http://google.com/" class="btn-primary-large">
      Example single-class link
  </a>
  ```

I think this makes it pretty obvious why the first approach is much more flexible and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your response, makes prefect sense now! I think if he'd of said something along the lines of "add a further 5 types of button as well as 3 additional sizes of each" it would have been easier for me to understand.

Comment: Should your example multi-class link be `btn btn-primary btn-large`?  At the moment it's a single class.

Comment: @davidpauljunior - you're right, I have edited the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Probably even beter would be to utilize the power of sass and do

```
.whatever-name {
    @extend %btn;
    @extend %btn-primary;
    @extend %btn-large;
}
```